# Sorting an Array List of String[] arrays

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I am reading in a `.csv` file sort of like a spreadsheet in excel. There are a certain number of columns, determined by the file, and I read each line into a string array using the `.split(",")` method. I then put this into an array list so it can hold all of the string arrays without giving it a specific size. However, when I go to sort the array list using `Collections.sort()`, the program breaks. What could the problem be? Here is my code to sort:

```
Collections.sort(stringList, new Comparator < String[] > () {
    public int compare(String[] strings, String[] otherStrings) {
        return -1 * (strings[sortNum].compareTo(otherStrings[sortNum]));
    }
});
```

Comment: Where does `sortNum` come from?

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"? Where doesn't it break? What error do you get? What did you expect to happen?  Does every row have `sortNum`+1 cells?

Comment: Are you sure that `sortNum` is not out of the bounds of either `String[]`?

Comment: I assume sortNum is the column number you want to reverse sort by. I also assume its a String which you want to have ASCIIbetical sorting on.

Comment: how does it break? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: There's no error when it breaks, it just says program terminated. sortNum is a static variable used to sort by a given column specified by the user.

Comment: This is not the cause of your problem, but I hope you are aware that split(",") is not valid for parsing csv files in general. Specifically, many csv implementations allow for commas inside double-quoted fields. Hopefully it is easy for you to verify this is not the case for your data. Incidentally, if this caused your arrays to be different lengths, then it could cause an error if sortNum was hitting the end of one of the (incorrectly split) rows and was out of bounds in another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two points:

- *Don't* multiply the result of `compare` by -1 to reverse a comparison. `Integer.MIN_VALUE * -1` is still `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Instead, reverse the order of the comparison itself
- My guess is that you've *actually* got some rows without enough columns. Perhaps you should put those at the end?

Something like:

```
Collections.sort(stringList, new Comparator < String[] > () {
    public int compare(String[] x1, String[] x2) {
        if (x1.length > sortNum && x2.length > sortNum) {
            return x2[sortNum].compareTo(x1[sortNum]); 
        }
        if (x1.length > sortNum) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (x2.length > sortNum) {
            return -1;
        }
        return x2.length - x1.length;
    }
});
```

Alternatively, filter your list first to make absolutely *sure* that all rows have enough columns.

Answer (score 1):

Well, either strings[sortNum] or otherStrings[sortNum] could be out of bounds. You need to do some checks to prevent that. Also, strings[sortNum] or otherStrings[sortNum] could be null. I bet you're running into one of these 2 things. What does the call stack indicate?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

First your class comparator with a constructor:

```
public class MyStringArrayComparator implements Comparator<String[]>{

       Integer sortNum;

       public MyStringComparator(Integer index) {
              sortNum = index;
       }

       @Override
       public int compare(String[] strings, String[] otherStrings) {
              return -1*(strings[sortNum].compareTo(otherStrings[sortNum]));
       }
}
```

and in your code

```
Collections.sort(stringList,new MyStringArrayComparator<String[]>(index));
```

Hope that works for you

Answer (score 1):

Sharing code in case someone need to do the sort on multiple columns.

```java
public final class ArrayComparatorWithIndex<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<T[]>
{
    private final int[] indexToSort;

    public ArrayComparatorWithIndex(int[] indexToSort)
    {         
        if(indexToSort == null || indexToSort.length == 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index to use for sorting cannot be null or empty.");
        }
        this.indexToSort = indexToSort;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T[] str, T[] otherStr)
    { 
        int result= 0;
        for (int index : indexToSort)
        {
            result= str[index].compareTo(otherStr[index]);
            if (result != 0){
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

//Example how to use it:  
int[] indexForSorting= new int[] { 1, 3 };
Collections.sort(stringList, new ArrayComparatorWithIndex<String>(indexForSorting));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might have a closure problem in reference to the 'sortNum' variable.  See [Jon Skeet's closure article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) for some guidance, even though it deals with closures in C# it should still be relevant.  Even if you don't have this issue, it's a good read.  :)

Answer (score 0):

you can provide default values for empty "cells":

```
            public int compare(String[] strings, String[] otherStrings) {
                String one, other;
                one = other = ""; // default value
                if (sortNum<strings.length && strings[sortNum] != null) {
                    one = strings[sortNum];
                }
                if (sortNum<otherStrings.length && otherStrings[sortNum] != null) {
                    other = otherStrings[sortNum];
                }
                return -1 * (one.compareTo(other));
            }
```